# What's the best way to replace this sink supply line?

Tags: plumbing, bathroom, sink

When removing a pedestal sink to put tile underneath, I busted one of the supply lines. I know I can get a flexible mesh supply line at the store, but I don't see any threaded connection on my wall side. Is this a normal way of installing supply lines? What's the best way to proceed from here?
Also, what are the pros and cons of the new mesh style vs the ribbed style I have now?

[image: broken supply line]

Comment: you could get a new FI stop Tap and put a nipple in it to connect to the nut that you have coming out of the wall

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The broken supply line appears to be integral to the shutoff valve.  You will need to replace the valve with something like [this](http://www.homedepot.com/p/BrassCraft-1-2-in-NOM-Comp-Inlet-x-3-8-in-OD-Comp-Outlet-Chrome-Plated-Brass-Multi-Turn-Angle-Valve-OCR19-C1/100050807)

[image: shutoff valve]

You may wish to consider replacing both of them and installing new flexible supply lines.

Comment: Ok. Is that going to involve soldering? I've done electrical soldering, but never with pipes. And can you explain why anyone would install a supply line integral to the valve? Seems like a lot of trouble whenever something breaks.

Comment: The large nut behind the attachment point of the supply line looks like a screw connection. You need to try to grab the pipe behind that to avoid putting too much strain on the connection in the wall, and then use an adjustable wrench to remove the nut. If the pipe is threaded, you need a threaded valve, not a compression fitting. I agree that the integral supply line seems like a bad idea. Pipe soldering is a bit of a challenge and usually involves torches, not soldering irons, and knowledge as to how to get a solid joint, and it's close to a wall. If it is a solder joint, call a pro.

Comment: Based on the location of greenish mineral deposits, the first hex fitting closest to the wall appears to be a female pipe thread adapter. Soak this area with WD-40, then hold the adapter firm with an adjustable wrench while attempting to turn the valve body with vise or mole grips. If I'm wrong and this is a compression fitting, it should still loosen this way, but you will find the hex part will turn as well. It doesn't really look like a soldered connection, but it's hard to tell from a picture. If bib is right, nothing will happen or the valve will break, no loss.

Comment: @bcworkz Better first approach.

Answer (score 0):

These types of valves are notorius for freezing up as they get old.  They are typically poorly made. I suggest replacing both of them.